# "Embedding" JasperServer into external web app?

Tags: java, web-applications, jasper-reports, jasperserver

is there any way to integrate/embed JasperServer into another web app?
The thing is that the login page of JasperServer should be somehow bypassed. Is it maybe possible to do authentication through web service / REST, skip login page, and then show the main server page in an *iframe*, or something to that effect?

Thanks.

Comment: The link is about JasperServer web service. I cannot find any info about JasperServer servlets.

Comment: JasperReports 5.2 has created a guide on various types of embedding: http://www.jaspersoft.com/embedding-bi-a-jaspersoft-guide-to-embedding-jaspersoft-into-your-application If you are looking for seamless Single Sign On, I recommend reading through this wiki article
http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/jasperreports-server-authentication-reference
It covers options such as JAAS, CAS, LDAP, JBoss SSO, etc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Http protocol and pull the reports in an iframe. The authentication information needs to go in URL as j_username and j_password.

To use Rest service, you need to write a REST client (I did it using Jersey with Http authentication) where authentication info goes in the Header.

It also provides SOAP services for integration which I haven't tried yet.

Comment: Passing j_username and j_password in url is not a secured way. Anyone having access to html source can see those credentials and any unauthorized user can download  the report without even going thru authentication process.

Answer (score 2):

JasperServer Authentication is implemented by Spring Security, so you can use a SSO mechanism supported by Spring Security easily.
You can find XML configuration file (for the security) easily.